# how to use fixtures in Yii framework for TDD?

Tags: php, oracle, yii, tdd

how to use fixtures in Yii framework for TDD ?, here's how I understand it

```
 - I create a fixture like e.g users.php
 - I add the table inside the testdrive.db file located inside the protected/data folder
 - I create a unit test like e.g unit/UsersTest.php

then I run phpunit unit/UsersTest.php
```

this is the real question of mine that bothers me, should the fixtures tables also be existing in the actual database ?, or the fixtures & testdrive.db will only work if the table actually exist in the real db ?

Comment: I normally create a separate test database in any case, because my unit tests include testing the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answe is in the Yii framework website, the documentation says, use e.g :Post (the semicolon) in the value of the fixture array, if that table does not exist in the real database nor has an existing model.that's how I understand it